# How can I determine the maximum supported resolution on a given Macbook?

Tags: display, thunderbolt, resolution

I recall that Macbooks produced in 2009-2011 supported a maximum *external* resolution (through Thunderbolt or DVI) of `2560x1600`.

An aspect ratio of `16:10` is much more useful for those who use their Macbooks mostly for work, rather than entertainment. The aspect ratio of `16:9` is more suitable for entertainment.

Yet Macbooks produced starting in 2012, and before supporting 4K external resolution, appear to provide only `2560x1440` (which is `16:9`).

It's really a pity, because this may be one factor why it's impossible to find `2560x1600` monitors in the 24" and 27" variety. To get `16:10` one must move all the way to the cumbersome 30", and then the DPI is hardly impressive.

But before buying any monitor for a "legacy" Macbook, it's nice to know for sure.

How do I determine the maximum *external* resolution supported on a given Macbook? Is this available in `System Information...`? I see the type of graphics card there, but not the resolution. Under `Thunderbolt` I see the speed (10GB/s x2), but not the resolution.

Comment: Be aware that on some MacBook models the maximum resolution published by Apple may be lower than actual maximums supported by the hardware. Both the hardware component manufacturers’ spec sheets and users’ anecdotes suggest you may achieve higher resolutions when plugging in certain monitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I don't normally like to post 'link only' answers, this needs to be an exception.  The answer to your question will largely be 'it depends on the MacBook'.

To help you figure it out, I recommend going to [EveryMac.com's MacBook Pro section](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/index-macbookpro.html).  This site will list the technical specs of every MacBook, including the **maximum external resolution**.

For example, here's a partial tech spec for a 2010 13" MBP:

[image]

Comment: I agree it would be nicer to have get the data from Apple directly but I'm not aware of method to do it (apart from clicking on the Apple logo on each model).  For several years I've been using EveryMac.com as my resource on everything related to Apple hardware.

Comment: @Calaf You can get some info from the command line:  `system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType`  It will tell you what your *current resolution* is.  Unfortunately, any info that it presents is not helpful because in the end it comes down to the display that it's connected to - and those are all different which is why you can't get that info.  You need to refer to the actual specs of the model Mac you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get this from the Graphics/Displays selection in the System Report from clicking on the Apple logo!

Comment: And that is why the EveryMac.com's approach is the best!